# Forward ssh connection to Android devices

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, virtualization, android

In my lab I want to set up a ssh jump host that forwards incoming ssh connections to Android devices that are connected to it via USB. All Android devices have USB-tethering turned on. The tethering connection spawns a network adapter in the sub net 192.168.42.0/24 for each Android device. Every Android device runs a ssh server on a different port. The setup is illustrated in the following:

[image: exemplary setup with two devices]

My idea is to forward ssh connections according to the port. Therefore, I added the network adapters to a bridge and forwarded the connections via iptables. I made up the following for this purpose:

```
sudo ip link add name ogt type bridge
sudo ip l set eno1 master ogt 
sudo ip l set usb0 master ogt 
sudo ip l set usb1 master ogt
sudo ip a a 192.168.42.1/24 dev ogt
sudo ip link set ogt up

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ogt -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.42.0/24 -o eno1 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.1.100
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 130 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.130:130
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.42.130 --dport 130 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 131 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.131:131
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.42.131 --dport 130 -j ACCEPT
```

The setup works but I have no internet on the jump host. Unfortunately, I do not quite understand why. How can I improve the forwarding or is there maybe a better solution? I would be very happy to have a helping hand!

Comment: I just realized that I made a mistake in the sketch. The incoming connection is not on port 22, it is on port 130 or 131 depending on the device I want to connect to. I hope it is not too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little while I got it working. Instead of iptables I use `adb forward`.

Therefore, start adb so that it listens on all local interfaces:

```
sudo adb -a nodaemon server start
```

The -a option makes adb listen on all local interfaces. Start adb without it if you only want to work locally.

Afterwards use `adb forward` to forward incoming ssh connections to the respective port on the Android device:

```
adb -s [serialDevice#1] forward tcp:130 tcp:130
adb -s [serialDevice#2] forward tcp:131 tcp:131
```

This forwards incoming connections on port 130/131 to the respective Android device. Using `ssh root@172.16.1.100 -p130` or `ssh root@172.16.1.100 -p131` I can now connect to the desired device

Here are some resources I used to research about this problem:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130335/adb-port-forwarding-to-listen-on-all-interfaces
- https://pencilflip.medium.com/how-to-use-adb-forward-6a8cbfa04907
- https://blog.usejournal.com/adb-port-forwarding-and-reversing-d2bc71835d43